# UIView animate doesn't finish before Label is hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

My label is disappearing before the animation runs.

The animation should run after a button is pressed and slide out a label and the Button. But when I press the button they are both hidden before the animation can slide them out.

```
func nextGame() {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
            NSLog("Animation started")
            self.labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.x + 500, y: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
            self.buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.x + 500, y: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
        }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
            NSLog("Animation stopped")
            self.labelWinningPlayer.isHidden = true
            self.buttonNextGameLabel.isHidden = true
    })


    //sets buttons to start position
    labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: labelWinningPlayer.center.x - 1000, y: labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
    buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: buttonNextGameLabel.center.x - 1000, y: buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)

    //hides buttons that lay under the animated buttons 
    for i in 1...9 {

        if let button = view.viewWithTag(i) as? UIButton {
            button.setImage(nil, for: .normal)
        }
    }
    activeGame = true
}

//animation should get started with this button
@IBAction func buttenNextGameAction(_ sender: Any) {
    nextGame()
}

//slides buttons in
func slideNextGameButtons() {

    labelWinningPlayer.isHidden = false
    buttonNextGameLabel.isHidden = false

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {

        self.labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.x + 500, y: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.x + 500, y: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
    })
}
```

Here is the NSLog. According to that it's running the full animation...

```
2017-11-15 23:26:17.321465 [2442:245232] Animation started
2017-11-15 23:26:20.325137 [2442:245232] Animation stopped
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Do the label and button get hidden at the start (animation started) or at the end (animation ended)?

Comment: Are your label and button positioned by autolayout constraints?

Comment: They should get hidden when the animation has ended. And no they  aren't positioned by auto layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works perfectly:

[image]

Therefore something that you have *not* told us about is causing whatever the problem is.

**EDIT**: And yes indeed, it was the code you didn't tell us about that causes the problem. You told us about this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        self.labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.x + 500, y: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.x + 500, y: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        self.labelWinningPlayer.isHidden = true
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.isHidden = true
})
```

But you didn't tell us about the *next* lines, which are this:

```
labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: labelWinningPlayer.center.x - 1000, y: labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: buttonNextGameLabel.center.x - 1000, y: buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
```

Those lines cancel the animation!

It seems you have not understood what an animation is. You animate first, and anything you want done *after* the animation, you put into the `completion` function. But those lines *are* something you want done *after* the animation. So put them into the `completion` function! Like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
        self.labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.x + 500, y: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.x + 500, y: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        self.labelWinningPlayer.isHidden = true
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.isHidden = true
        labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: labelWinningPlayer.center.x - 1000, y: labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
        buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: buttonNextGameLabel.center.x - 1000, y: buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
        // ... and everything else in the method goes here too
})
```

And everything else in the method needs to be moved in there too. Everything that is to happen *after* the completion of the animation goes into the `completion` function. That is what `completion` means!

Comment: I've edited the code in the question to all code that relate to the buttons. Maybe you see something there? Or could there be a problem in the storyboard?

Comment: Yup, it’s the additional code, that you didn’t originally show us, that is causing the problem. Move all of it into the `completion` function so it happens after the animation ends.

Comment: Edited my answer to show you what i mean. Next time you ask a question, show your code instead of hiding it! You'll get better help, faster.

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm quite new to programming and stackoverflow. And now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

set the label and the button's super view clipsToBounds property to true

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, delay: 0.0, options: [], animations: {
        NSLog("Animation started")
        self.labelWinningPlayer.center = CGPoint(x: (self.labelWinningPlayer.center.x) * 3, y: self.labelWinningPlayer.center.y)
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.center = CGPoint(x: (self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.x) * 3, y: self.buttonNextGameLabel.center.y)
    }, completion: { (finished: Bool) in
        NSLog("Animation stopped")
        self.labelWinningPlayer.isHidden = true
        self.buttonNextGameLabel.isHidden = true
    })
```